# unwanted page reload when dynamicly adding iframe

Tags: javascript, iphone, firefox, iframe, reload

**Looks like its an Firefox Home strict problem, and as Mozzilla dropped the support for it and pulled it out if iStore, there is I guess no point in trying to get workaround (http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/08/31/mozilla-retires-firefox-home-ios-releases-source-code-github/), anyway i ve posted bug to them (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853377) if someone is interested in following/solwing**

---

I ve got quite nice crossbrowsing library using iframe method to communicate.

And it works beatifull untill .. opened with Firefox on iPhone. Pages with library starts, and then magicly are redirected.

Well I ve went into the code and tried identify the problem:

After dynamically adding iframe parent reloads to iframe src. I have tested following:

1. `document.createElement('iframe')` appending to document
2. `document.createElement('iframe')` appending to precreated div
3. `.innerHTML` method with precreated iframe code in it
4. `frames['iframe_name'].location.src` with precreated iframe with empty src
5. `.location.assign()`

   - with `document.getElementById()`fails
   - with `frames['iframe_name']` redirect
6. same with jquery 
   `$('<iframe src="link"/>'). appendTo('#reportA');`
7. tried also first create iframe without src and then set it
8. also update with `$('#iframe').attr('src','link')` cause redirect

Additionally, i see on logs (called page in iframe is logging status).
That infact there was like two calls, so it looks like first  the appended iframe reads in, then opends iframe src in new page.

While dissecting my code i found out that problem occurs when iframe is created in part of code, that was dynamically added by my js loader. I ve used following append scripts

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
var script = null;  
script = document.createElement('script');  
script.type = 'text/javascript';  
var tag = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);  
script.src =  GLOBAL_VARIABLE_WITH_PATH_TO_URL+'jsc/include.js?'+tag ;  
head.appendChild(script);
```

also tried

```
 document.write("<script src='"+FUTUREclickINFOpathS+"fcijsc/fci-include.js?"+tag+"'><\/script>");
```

UPDATE

Also tried to append irame on jquery `$(document).ready()` - when used with `document.write` method it works fine, till calling the appending in `setTimeout`

What is even more strange, when used `setTimeout()` in main static js file the same things happen. I ll try today `setInterval()` and see whats happening.

So as it obvious that any change on src of iframe cause parent reload, even if iframe was precreated. Any ideas why?

ps. sorry for some uncomprehensive sentences but i got my head wrapped around that issue

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried changing url / src with <IFrameElement>.location.assign(string url)

Comment: So you're saying that when you try to change the `src` property on the iframe, the parent page reloads? If you leave all your script intact and only comment out the line where the iframe src is changed, everything works correctly (except the iframe, of course)?

Comment: use the pre-created iframe, but have the initial src attribute set to an actual page ie. www.yourdomain.tld/blank.htm then when you change it with $('#premadeIframeID').attr('src', newURL); it should be ok.

Comment: chris: yes, evetyrhing works fine till iframe appaeding - i ve commenteng almost all of the library, left just elf diagnostic function, that trigers after 10 seconds, to see were is the process. its running on domainA, appends iframe to domainB if found a problem, err_code is passed in url

Comment: Lastcoder - cant do that, i run on clients domain were i m not allowed to precreate anything. but i shall give it a try with jQuery changing src.

Comment: I'm running in to the exact same problem with a library I recently wrote https://github.com/artsy/scroll-frame. It's very strange, if you go here http://artsy.github.io/scroll-frame/demo.html and run `$('body').append("<iframe>"); $('iframe').attr('src', 'http://artsy.github.io/scroll-frame/detail.html#width=462')` in the console it will do the same weird reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `postMessage` to communicate from the iframe to the parent? I ran into this and noticed that removing `parent.postMessage` from the iframe's scripts fixed it. I'll update with a way to work around this if I find one.